# problem with ascii encoding in python3 when trying to create a csv file

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, writer

So, I am trying to write some information into a csv file encoded in utf-8 but it is not letting me citing the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Error: There're some errors in the lambda funtion process - 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa1' in position 602: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the writer I am using in order to convert a list of values into data rows is:

```
writer = csv.writer(output, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

I tried installing `unicodecsv` and using it but it didn't play nice with some of the characters.

If I try to do a list comprehension for every row written by the writer usinfg the following function y end up with `b's` in every entry in the csv which should not be since I really need it to be plaintext.

Comment: Show us the data you're attempting to write that is causing the error.

Comment: Maybe this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: If you're using Python 3, there's no need to use `unicodecsv`. Instead, you need to make sure the `output` stream is opened with `encoding='utf8'`.

Comment: Please add a bit more code, showing how you open the file and write the rows.